# Python - Django error al crear super user

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-models

estoy creando un servicio de gestion de alumnos. Una ves que termine de diseñar los modelos hago las migraciones (makemigrations y migrate) de mis apps, sin problemas. Pero al intentar crear un super user sale este error:

```
Nombre de usuario: Admin
Dirección de correo electrónico: admin@mail.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",line 85, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-    packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in execute
     return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.alumnos_materiasalumno__old
```

Estoy usando django 2.1.4 con sqlite3 en python 3.7.
[Traceback en pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hmKjqHvy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es de django 2.1.4 con sqlite3 (3.26), parece que hay un error ya marcado https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182. Mi solucion fue simplemente ir a usar una database de produccion, postgresql en mi caso y todo funciona perfecto.

La solución, si es **necesario** utilizar sqlite3, es esperar que django 2.1.5 salga en enero del 2019 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1.5/), actualizar el projecto a la nueva version y reconstruir la base de datos de sqlite3.

Comment: si bien estos enlaces pueden resolver tu pregunta, la idea es dar detalles aqui mismo en vez de solo colocar los links

Comment: En mi caso la solucion para este problema es esperar el release de django 2.1.5. No se si serviria simplemente comentar eso.

Comment: dale editar a tu reespuesta añade eso y la explicación de que será resuelto en django 2.1.5